# this.find is not a function, Mongoose Schema design

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm currently writing a function that will create a notification for every User that is in the committee of a specified Society (It's a social network site btw) and whenever I run this:

```
User.statics.newSocietyNotification = function(req, socID, typeID, url, next){
  var tmpUsers = []
  Society.findById(socID, function(err, doc){
    console.log(doc)

    doc.committee.forEach(function(comMember, i){
      tmpUsers.push(comMember._uid)
    })
    this.find({'_id' : { $in : tmpUsers } }, function(err, docs){
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
      if(docs.length == 0 || docs == null){
        next(false)
      }
      next(docs)
      console.log(docs)
    })
  })
}
```

It crashes the server with this message:

```
TypeError: this.find is not a function
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/models/user.js:368:10
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3324:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate the help :)

EDIT: 
Using User.find instead of 'this'

```
TypeError: User.find is not a function
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/models/user.js:368:10
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3324:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Comment: Are you trying to find `User` or `Society`? Just use the relevant model again, instead of using `this`. That way you don't need to hope / assume `this` is being bound to what you expect.

Comment: try ` Society.find`

Comment: See edit, still get the same error for some reason

Comment: Ah, I answered before I saw your update. `User` is for sure a mongoose model?

Comment: Thats fine :P User is definitely a model, I've been using it without fail for the past month :P

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` on line 368 is referring to context of the callback function of the `findById` method. That callback function (which is an object, under the hood) doesn't have a method called `find`.

Instead, use `Society.find(...` or `User.find(...` to look up something else in the database.